# strongloop slc env-set not possible before deploy?

Tags: node.js, deployment, strongloop

Was looking at the docs to set up a few apps deployed to strong-pm but ran into a cart-before-the-horse type issue:

> It's not possible to set environment variables using `slc ctl env-set <service> FOO=bar...` *before* an app is deployed and given a service name.

This means that you are *forced to run your app initially in a failure state* upon first deploy, which is inconvenient and probably not a huge deal, but was curious if this is known.

Would be awesome if the `slc ctl env-set` command could set up a service name just like slc deploy does, but without the deploy itself.

As an aside, was curious if `slc pm-install/sl-pm-install -e "FOO=bar"` actually works to set common/shared/global env vars, but I couldn't find where these vars were set when the command was run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you deploy an app for the first time it auto-creates a service if one doesn't exist as part of the process. This can also be done manually with `slc ctl create default`. If you do that manually, you can modify the environment with `slc ctl env-set default FOO=bar BAR=foo` before running `slc deploy`.

Note that `default` is just a name, and if you want to use a name other then `default` you will have to specify it when you deploy with `slc deploy -s customName` since `default` is the default name.

Comment: Ran into a strange state where I used `slc ctl create svcname` and ended up with 2 services when I used `slc deploy -s svcname`. One was #3 and the other #4, neither of them were started.

Comment: Doesn't seem like this is that robust yet...I used `slc create` and then `slc deploy` using the same service name, but still have strange behavior with `env-set`. Some env vars are remembered across `slc ctl remove` ops, which is unexpected. I'm still racing to set env vars so my app doesn't stall with a bunch of mongo conn failures at boot, making it impossible to use `slc ctl` for anything; just get "socket hang up" after 90s or so...

Comment: @Brian can you open an issue? https://github.com/strongloop/strong-pm/issues (including `slc version` from the client and `sl-pm --version` from the server)